# Is there active research on topological groups?

Tags: topological-groups, advice, research

So I came across something called "Topological Groups". I have just taken a course on topology/and some basic algebraic topology which i really liked.
My mind was blown. I said topological groups are awesome. But then i thought ... are they still useful?

I heard general topology is dead but is it a branch of general topology or not?. Can they still provide usefulness to the other parts of math like harmonic analysis physics or pdes as i read they used to, or  new methods for these problems  have replaced topological groups.

So all these sum up to the following question ! What's the status on this subject (active or dead)  and is it considered an area of research and what is it called?

Comment: Look up Lie groups, which are topological groups also equipped with a smooth structure. They are ubiquitous. More general topological groups are useful, but I don't know much about them.

Comment: You should edit this question to be less rambling and more to the point.

Comment: @AndresMejia i saw lie group methods for diff eq. Is not doing well.

Comment: upvoted for your enthusiasm, and I edited some of it. I know very little on current research, but here is one place to look: http://search.arxiv.org:8081/?query=topological+group&in=. It looks like there are tons of applications to physics. I know there are many references on the subject as well.

Comment: @AndresMejia i edited aswell thanks!!!

Comment: I believe that all branches of mathematics are currently very active.

Comment: I'd really like a reference to your claim that general topology is dead, because it's definitely not.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-point-set-topology-a-dead-field

Comment: There is a suitable tag (research) that maybe can be interesting in this post. Good luck.